# Calling restful webservice and want to send XML as string using Apache Camel

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-camel

I have 3 party webservice which I want to call and put xml into it. I have using apache camel.

1. This is the XML which I wanted to put on the webservice:

> 

```
<parameter>
  <name>LastModified</name>
  <value>2015-11-24 11:15:38.0</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <name>UpdatedAttribute</name>
  <value>PORT2PROVISIONSTATUS</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <name>NewValue</name>
  <value>Configured</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <name>EntityType</name>
  <value>Pluggable</value>
</parameter>   </parameterSet>
```

2. Endpoint is 
   http://localhost:8080/RestfulWebService/crunchify/dspservice
3. Client implementation which I cannot change:

   ```
   @Path("{event}")     
   @GET    
   @Produces("application/json")   
   public String getICLEvent(@PathParam("event") String event) 
   {       
   System.out.println("ICL Event :: "+ event);         
   String result = "@Produces(\"application/xml\") Output: \n\nICL Event: \n\n" + event;       
   return result;  
   }
   ```

**What I have tried so far:**

I have used Camel http component in my route like:

```
.convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
                            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://localhost:8080/RestfulWebService/crunchify/dspservice/${in.body}"))
                            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                            //.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, constant("event=${in.body}"))
                            //.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/form-urlencoded"))
                            .to("http://localhost:8080/RestfulWebService/crunchify/dspservice")
```

In which I am trying to pass the complete string in the header key 'CamelHttpUri', but I am getting the `java.net.URISyntaxException:` exception.

I am not sure this is the best way to call/produce the restful webservice, please suggest the better way I have found hard way to find anything over the internet.

Comment: In REST a producing call is done with HTTP method POST or PUT. Possibly that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Camel Restlet instead?
http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html
An example here:

```
.convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
.to("restlet:http://localhost:" + portNum + "/?restletMethod=GET");
```